# Recover folder path images stored in app Photos (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, finder

I bookmarked some photos stored in app Photos (Mac Software) into folders in Google Chrome. It was a research that i was doing. I was simple dragging the image from Photos into Chrome Browser and bookmarking them.

But now, when i try to open these images, the system can't find the photos anymore. I guess app Photos changed the parameters/location of these images.

All images that i have bookmarked in chrome were saved within this folder path parameter:

```
file:///Users/Admin/Pictures/Library%20Photos.photoslibrary/resources/proxies/derivatives/82/00/82dc/UNADJUSTEDNONRAW_thumb_82dc.jpg
```

Now, i can't find none of it anymore. It was a long research, i really need to find them. Is that a way to recover/discover where they are stored now?

Comment: You should ask this in https://apple.stackexchange.com/ There's nothing related to mac developing or regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

If your photos were displayed in the Photos, all original images are saved in `/Users/Admin/Pictures/Library Photos.photoslibrary/originals`
Try to search there.

Comment: Thank you for attempting to answer. "[How do I write a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)"
is useful, especially the "Answer well-asked questions" section. The question asked is off-topic for SO, so, instead of answering, you should help the site by redirecting the question to where it really belongs.